# Search and reload datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a existing datagridview and a search textbox.

When I type a search text and click on the search button based on the below method (using stored procedures), I like to have it auto reload the datagridview with the search results.

How can I achieve this?

```
public static void searchAny(String searchFields, String tblName, String connectionString, SqlCommand tblscmd, SqlDataAdapter tbldataadaptor, DataTable tbldatatable, SqlCommandBuilder cmbuilder, DataGridView DataGridViewName)
{
    using (SqlConnection tblconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        tblconn.Open();
        SqlCommand tblcmd = new SqlCommand();
        tblcmd.Connection = tblconn;
        tblcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        tblcmd.CommandText = "usp_searchany";
        tblcmd.Parameters.Add("@stringToFind", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        tblcmd.Parameters["@stringToFind"].Value = "%" + searchFields + "%";
        tblcmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        tblcmd.Parameters["@table"].Value = tblName;
        cmbuilder.DataAdapter = tbldataadaptor;
        tbldatatable.DefaultView.AllowDelete = true;
        tbldatatable.DefaultView.AllowEdit = true;
        tbldataadaptor.Fill(tbldatatable);
        DataGridViewName.ReadOnly = false;
        DataGridViewName.DataSource = tbldatatable;
        tblconn.Close();
    }
}


private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbldatatable.Clear();
    String searchFields = SearchTextBox.Text;
    GeneralMethods.searchAny(searchFields, "tblClients", connectionString, tblcmd, tbldataadaptor, tbldatatable, cmbuilder, dataGridView);
    dataGridView.DataSource = tbldatatable;
    dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Is the grid being filled?

Comment: I used the above method and it does not return the search results and there is not refresh of datatable / datagridview.

Comment: You need to clear the datagridview, bind and refresh.

Comment: Hi Kangkan, I tried the clear, bind and refresh. Doesn't seems to work. My edited code is updated to my question above. Can help to see if my code is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/b059f1cb-c216-44f5-8ee6-7b78a2b2c4d1

Comment: Silly me.

I missed the selectCommand.

    tbldataadaptor.SelectCommand = tblcmd;

This teaches me not to work long hours without break.
Thanks for all assistance anyway... 

You guys rocks....!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter your DataGridView's DataSource...like the following way...It's not required to clear,bind or refresh the datagridview...

From the CellEndEidt this is possible....

Simply you can filter the DataGridView's DataSource

```
private void MyDataGrid1_CellEndEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 0)
       {
        if (myDataGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            MyFilterString="Field1=Feild2 and Field3>Field4";
        }
        MyDtb1.DefaultView.RowFilter = FilterString;
    }
}
```